# how to insert Personalization element inside another Personalization in exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am working on exact target to trigger email template to customers.

let say i have one Personalization element `%%url_A%%` and this `url_A` contains html another Personalization element `%%url_B%%`

Example:

Template: `<table><tr><td>%%url_A%%</td><tr></table>`

url_A : Hi, Welcome to our services to proceed further please clink on this url: `<a href="%%url_B%%"></a>`

url_B : `http://www.example.com`

so using exact target i am able to replace `%%url_A%%` in html template but url_B not replacing.

Please suggest an answer to resolve this issue.

Comment: You'll need quotes around your `%%url_B%%` href: `<a href="%%url_B%%">link</a>`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
%%[

var @url_A
set @url_A = AttributeValue("url_A")

output(concat("<br>url_A (before): ", @url_A))

set @url_A = treatAsContent(@url_A)

output(concat("<br>url_A (after): ", @url_A))

]%%
```

The [**TreatAsContent**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/treatascontent.htm) function forces the AMPscript to get re-evaluated.